# Moment generating function for independent random variables

Tags: probability, moment-generating-functions

> Suppose that $X_1, X_2$, and $X_3$ are identically distributed independent discrete random variables with probabilities given by...
>
> - $1/3$ if $x=0$
> - $2/3$ if $x=1$
> - $0$ else
>
> Find the moment generating function of $Y=X_1X_2X_3$

So far, I have the following

$\sum \exp(Yt)\cdot p(Y)$

but I have no idea where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** First find the *distribution* of $Y$. It is not hard, since $Y=1$ if all the $X_i$ are $1$, and $Y=0$ otherwise.

Comment: Yea, they are independent, I missed that.